# What are examples of the integration trick involving "Simultaneous Integrals," "Dual Integrals," or "Pairs of Integrals"?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration

I'm trying to get more apt at computing integrals, and I'm looking for examples of the particular integral technique of "Simultaneous Integrals," "Dual Integrals," or "Pairs of Integrals"?

[Here (in Method 2) is an example](https://qr.ae/pGbpfz) of the technique I'm looking to understand. The technique is used as one option for integrating $\sqrt{\tan(x)}$, wherein two integrals $I$ and $J$ are introduced and the values of $I+J$ and $I-J$ are computed/used to determine the desired value.

**My questions:**

1. What is this technique called? I included three names in my title; are any of those correct?
2. (the most important) What are some other examples of using this technique in integration? The more tractable / lower-level, the better: I'd like to be able to convey this to Calculus students.
3. (of lesser importance) What is the theoretical underpinnings of this technique that I need to be aware of? I've read that this is really a vector space basis situation at its core; is this really a linear algebra technique?

Down below, I collect some information:

**Is this question a duplicate?** Technically, yes. [This 8-year-old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436785/example-of-integral-pairs-or-triples-i-j-k) asks the same thing, but the answers there didn't really scratch the itch that I have.

**What I've found independently:**

- https://www.openbookpublishers.com/htmlreader/978-1-78374-142-7/Chapters/P26.html
- https://sci-hub.do/10.1080/10511971003742411
- https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974819

Comment: Partial fractions. E.g. if $x\ne \pm 1$ then $\frac {2}{1-x^2}=\frac {1}{1+x}+\frac {1}{1-x}. $ So if |$x|<1$ then $\int \frac {2}{1-x^2}dx=\ln (1+x)-\ln (1-x),$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet - Can you explain a bit more how this relates to the example given? I see how it's an example of $I+J$, but there's no mention of $I-J$ or any other relation between $I$ and $J$. Partial fractions seems like a much less exotic integral technique, but maybe you can shed some light on some aspect that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think the method you have in mind goes by any standard name though I have seen the phrase *"a system of relations involving integrals"* used.

Two indefinite examples include:

1. Let
   $$I = \int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\sin^3 x - \cos^3 x} \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad J = \int \frac{\cos^3 x}{\sin^3 x - \cos^3 x} \, dx.$$
   If $I - J$ and $I + J$ are first found, $I$ and $J$ can then be found.
2. Let
   $$I = \int \frac{1 + x^4}{1 - x^4} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^4}} \quad \text{and} \quad J = \int \frac{x^2}{1 - x^4} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^4}}.$$
   If
   $$A = \int \frac{1 + x^2}{1 - x^2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ 1 + x^4}} \quad \text{and} \quad B = \int \frac{1 - x^2}{1 + x^2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^4}},$$
   we see that
   $$I = \frac{1}{2}(A + B) \quad \text{and} \quad J = \frac{1}{4}(A - B).$$
   The integrals $A$ and $B$ can be found using, for example, a substitution $u = \sqrt{1 + x^4}/x$, from which $I$ and $J$ can then be found.

A few definite examples, at a slightly higher level of difficulty, include:

1. Let
   $$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log (\sin x) \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad J = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log (\cos x) \, dx.$$
   Finding $I - J$ and $I + J$ leads to values for $I$ and $J$.
2. Let
   $$I = \int_0^1 \frac{x \log (1 - x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad J = \int_0^1 \frac{x \log (1 + x)}{1 + x^2} \, dx.$$
   Again finding $I - J$ and $I + J$ leads to values for $I$ and $J$.
3. Let
   $$I = \int_0^1 \arctan (x) \log (1 - x) \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad J = \int_0^1 \arctan (x) \log (1 + x) \, dx.$$
   Again finding $I - J$ and $I + J$ leads to values for $I$ and $J$.

Answer (score 6):

The most famous one is probably one of the methods for working out the gaussian integral:
$$
I=\int\limits_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2}dx=\int\limits_{\mathbb R}e^{-y^2}dy\\
\Rightarrow I^2=\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2}dx\right)\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb R}e^{-y^2}dy\right)=\iint\limits_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dx\,dy
$$
although this feels like cheating a bit as really it is the same integral twice

---

I guess another one would be something like this:
$$B=\int e^x\sin(x)dx\\A=\int e^x\cos(x)dx\\A+Bj=\int e^{(1+j)x}dx$$
which cuts a corner compared to using integration by parts

Comment: $j$?  Did an engineer sneak into MSE :)?

Comment: @Alan. For those who don't "get it", engineers often use $i$ for electric current and $\pm j$ for $\pm\sqrt {-1}.$

Comment: @Alan an imposter is among us

Comment: $j^2=+1$ to anyone who's not an engineer.

Comment: What notation will engineers use once they discover split-complex numbers?

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar they don't use those dw

Answer (score 1):

A related example to this method seems the following. Let $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be even and continuous, and let $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
Consider
$$
I:=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(x)}{1+\exp(cx)} dx.
$$
The substitution $y=-x$ yields
$$
I=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(y)}{1+\exp(-cy)} dy.
$$
Thus
$$
I+I=\int_{-1}^1f(x) \left(\frac{1}{1+\exp(cx)}+\frac{1}{1+\exp(-cx)}\right)  dx
$$
$$
=\int_{-1}^1f(x) dx = 2\int_{0}^1f(x) dx.
$$
So (independent on $c$)
$$
I=\int_{0}^1f(x) dx.
$$
For example
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^4}{1+\exp(x)} dx= \frac{1}{5}.
$$
It is not exactly the method, as only the sum and not the difference of integrals is used, but it seems related.