# When $\int_{a}^{b} \big( f(x)+g(x) \big) \text{ d}x$ is easy to evaluate but $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \text{ d}x$ and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) \text{ d}x$ are not

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I would like to construct functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} \big( f(x)+g(x) \big) \text{ d}x$ is possible and easy to evaluate, but $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \text{ d}x$ and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) \text{ d}x$ are both hard or impossible to evaluate. How can we construct such (nontrivial) functions?

For example,
$$\int_{0}^{2} \big(\sqrt{1+x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x} \big) \text{ d}x = 6.$$
In this case, we apply some results of integrals of inverse functions.

So is there any idea to construct such integrals, other than the idea of inverse functions?

Can we do the same for some indefinite integrals as well?

Comment: Does $a=-\infty, b=\infty, f(x)=e^{-x^2}, g(x)=-e^{-x^2}$ fit your criterion?

Comment: I have no idea what you’re trying to do. Construct example integral problems? Since there is no difference between a function and a sum of functions, this question is not answerable at present imo

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can trivially use $g(x)=-f(x)$. Nontrivial examples are, perhaps, a bit more difficult to come by.

Comment: You can always play with algebraic identities: For instance take $f(x)=\sin^2(x)$, $g(x)=\cos^2(x)$. These individual integrals are not impossible, or even too hard, to get (even the indefinite ones), but more so than the integral of 1=f+g$.

Comment: @Clayton actually yes, I do not need that trivial case. I think you only understood my question.

Comment: @Jose27 and I said, I need for $f$ and $g$ to be hard or impossible.

Comment: You could probably integrate the result of a quotient rule derivative as an example.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436785/example-of-integral-pairs-or-triples-i-j-k/612995#612995) may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add more in future.

$1$:

> $$\int f = \int \log (\sqrt{1+x^2}+x  )\mathrm dx$$ and $$\int g =  \int\log (\sqrt{1+x^2}-x  )\mathrm dx$$

$2:$

> $$\int f = \int \sqrt{\tan x}\mathrm dx$$
> $$\int g = \int \sqrt{\cot x}\mathrm dx$$